# Using pip to download openpyxl

Tags: python, pip, installation, openpyxl

I am trying to install openyxl using pip and I write the following in my command window:

```
C:\Users\Tracking4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>$ pip install openpyxl
```

and get the following error message:

> '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/ is the source I am using for instructions

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not write the dollar sign, that's just a symbol that appears in Unix terminals. Try just this:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

To install `pip` on Windows:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

The $ just means you have to type it in the shell. It is not a part of the command. Open a command window and type:
cd C:\Users\Tracking4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

This changes to the right directory.
Then type:

pip install openpyxl

Comment: C:\Users\Tracking4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>pip install openpyx
l
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  - I thought that pip was automatically installed in python 3.5

Comment: Try running `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools` ([source](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel))

Comment: successfully installed setuptools-32.3.1 but when I then try to use"pip install openpyxl" it gives the same error " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external operable command"

Comment: just figured out that I had to be in the scripts folder in order to execute this command.